# Clarification regarding Apache AGE documentation 'Orderability Between different Agtypes'

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

On the page regarding compatibility ([here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/comparability.html))

It is mentioned that:-
The ordering of different Agtype, when using <, <=, >, >= from smallest value to largest value is:

1    Edge

2    Path

3    Map

4    Vertex

5    Edge

6    Array

7    String

8    Bool

9    Numeric, Integer, Float

10    NULL

Why is there Edge twice on number 1 and number 5?
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a typo. However, from the Apache Age github [repository](https://github.com/apache/age) and [specifically this file](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/agtype_util.c),  we can verify the correct order.

**Correct Order :**
The ordering of different Agtype, when using <, <=, >, >= from smallest value to largest value is:

1. Edge
2. Path
3. Map
4. Vertex
5. Array
6. String
7. Bool
8. Numeric, Integer, Float
9. NULL

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a typo in the documentation, it has some.
Edge is only in the no1 spot not in no5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).